# Multiple update_user_meta in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey guys, I have this points system on a project, everything works fine except that I can't add meta_values to multiple users.

I'm using `<?php update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ) ?>`  but this seems to not work with multiple users.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you simply pass an array with user_ids to `update_user_meta`? Then it won't work indeed.

Using a loop over all user_ids it should work:

```
foreach($user_ids as $user_id){
    update_user_meta($user_id, $key, $value);
}
```

Think about the SQL being generated, while keeping in mind the database design of WordPress. It has the table `wp_usermeta`, with columns `user_id`, `meta_key` and `meta_value`. That means that every meta value has a row in this table, for every user. You could use some code as

```
global $wpdb;

$ids = implode("', '", $user_ids);
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE {$wpdb->usermeta} SET meta_value = %s WHERE user_id IN ('{$ids}') AND meta_key = %s"), $value, $key);
```

However this would not work if the `meta_key` for a certain user does not exist yet. You would then need an `INSERT` statement, which you can't do in a batch.

Comment: Please post some more code then, or try to debug it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like;

```
$user_meta_fields = array ( 'first_name', 'last_name', 'account_type', 'vd_sub_name', 'description', 'vd_adress', 'vd_cp', 'vd_ville', 'vd_department', 'vd_region', 'vd_country', 'vd_tel', 'vd_gsm', 'vd_fax', 'url' );
        foreach($user_meta_fields as $user_meta_field){
            //echo "update_user_meta(".$user_id.", ".$user_meta_field.", ".$posted[$user_meta_field].");";
            update_user_meta($user_id, $user_meta_field, $posted[$user_meta_field]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I made:

```
/*
 * Optimized way to add multiple usermeta keys and values
 * @author Ivijan-Stefan Stipic
 */
if( !function_exists('bulk_update_user_meta') ) : function bulk_update_user_meta(int $user_id, array $meta_data) {
    global $wpdb;

    $transactions = 0;

    foreach ($meta_data as $meta_key => $meta_value) {
        $meta_data[$meta_key] = [
            'exists' => $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `{$wpdb->usermeta}` WHERE `user_id` = %d AND `meta_key` = %s",
                $user_id,
                $meta_key
            )) > 0,
            'value' => maybe_serialize($meta_value)
        ];
    }

    $wpdb->query('START TRANSACTION');

    foreach ($meta_data as $meta_key => $meta_object) {

        $meta_value = $meta_object['value'];

        if ( $meta_object['exists'] ) {
            if( $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
                "UPDATE `{$wpdb->usermeta}` SET `meta_value` = %s WHERE `user_id` = %d AND `meta_key` = %s",
                $meta_value,
                $user_id,
                $meta_key
            )) !== false ) $transactions++;
        } else {
            if( $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO `{$wpdb->usermeta}` (`user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (%d, %s, %s)",
                $user_id,
                $meta_key,
                $meta_value
            )) !== false ) $transactions++;
        }
    }

    $wpdb->query('COMMIT');

    clean_user_cache($user_id);

    return $transactions === count($meta_data);
} endif;
```

It is simple to use:

```
bulk_update_user_meta( $user_id, [
    'ivi_test__1' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__2' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__3' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__4' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__5' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__6' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__7' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__8' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__9' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__10' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__11' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__12' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
] );
```